# How do I transfer video to iPad and password protect it?

Tags: video, password, file-transfer, ipad

Is there a way to transfer videos to iPad but at the same time password protect it?  Or password protect a folder so that only people with a password can go into that folder?

Comment: Best app would be VLC: VLC for Mobile by VideoLAN https://appsto.re/hr/QR_WM.i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of applications doing this job: [VideoVault](http://www.tomsoft.co.uk/iphone/videovault.htm) (1$), [FolderLock](http://www.newsoftwares.net/folderlock/iphone/) (4$), and a free [LockDown](http://www.iphoneheat.com/2009/07/how-to-password-protect-applications-on-iphone/), but it requires your iPad to be [jailbroken](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/05/ipad-jailbreak-ready-for-download/). Sorry, didn't found anything that would be free and, ehm, completely legal.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer a video to Goodreader and store it in a password protected folder.  I'm not sure how difficult it would be to gain access to it, but it seems fine for casual protection.  GoodReader is free and is one of the "essential" apps for the iPad.  Sounds like Goodreader is for "books" but it also works fine for Audio and Video.

Best way to transfer is via iTunes.  Click on your iPad in the left navigation area in iTunes, pick the Apps tab, scroll down to the bottom and Click on Goodreader

Answer (score 0):

New App [Video Voltage](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/video-voltage/id406226653?mt=8) is perfect for protecting videos:

> Video Voltage is a secure way to store films and videos away from prying eyes. Upload videos from iTunes and move them to a vault of your choosing.
>
> During fullscreen playback, a hide button is available to quickly return to the default vault.